# aws memory consumption issues across instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

our RubyOnRails app is deployed across multiple (6) web instances on AWS. Lately, we've been experiencing a memory issue. Basically, the memory is not being properly allocated between instances. Some of them are being maxed out while other instances are not being used. Could it be a load balancer issue. We also don't have metrics about memory in aws. What are the possible causes and solutions to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "memory consumption across instances"? Each Amazon EC2 instance has its own RAM. Memory is not shared between instances. If some instances are experiencing memory exhaustion, it would be due to whatever is running on the instance. The load balancer should be sending equal traffic to all instances. What type of Load Balancer is being used?

Comment: Seems to a load balancer issue. What load balancer are you using. Enable custom metrics or logs on the EC2 instances to see how many requests each instances recieve.

Comment: We're using PGBouncer as a load balancer.